# Alfresco Share: How to retrieve one component message bundles?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'd like to reuse some of the document library bundles on a custom page.

I've been throught the code and seen that when the doclib webscript is loaded, it goes into that `setMessages()` function which initialise at the `Alfresco.messages.scope['Alfresco.DocumentList']` level.

The problem I have is obvisouly on my custom page I don't have any messages for the `Alfresco.DocumentList` scope available.

Is there any way to retrieve the document list bundles from a custom component or webscript, and pass it throught ftl or something else. I imagine all of this is internal to Spring surf but I can't see myself duplicates the bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of component bundles is that they are specific to that component only. The only way to include those messages is to include the component on your page (you could then hide it from view via CSS) - your other components would then be able to access the messages using the method you described.

However, you may find that this is not ideal, and in that case your only options are to physically copy the messages, or (bit hacky, but could work) use an extensibility module to overlay the contents of the `documentlist.get` web script over your custom web script.